# Can you iterate over a list of words and use a dictionary to keep track of the frequency(count) of each word?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, frequency

I want to iterate over a list of words and use a dictionary to keep track of the frequency(count) of each word? Using something like this below :

`{'Number': Frequency, '2':2, '3':2}`

Comment: `from collections import Counter; Counter(your_list_of_words)`

Answer (score 1):

Please use `Counter` = ]

```
from collections import Counter

some_list = [2,3,4,5,6,6,6,2]
count_dict = Counter(some_list)

print(count_dict)

  Counter({2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 3})
```